# A simple views question for django/jQuery calls

Tags: jquery, django

I'm trying to figure out how to pass html back to a jQuery call, but for some reason my code refuses to work.

```
t = get_template('success.html')
html = t.render(Context({'success': True}))    # should render '<p><h1>aoeu</h1></p>'
x = "{'success' : '" + html + "'}"
return HttpResponse(x)
```

jQuery code:

```
$.post("adduser", data, function(responseData){
    $('#content').html(responseData.success);
}, "json");
```

if I replace html with a literal string (just 'asdf' or something), #content changes correctly. If I use the rendered html, it doesn't show. What am I doing wrong? Also, is this the correct way to make a dynamic call with django?

Comment: Do you get what you expect if you do alert(responseData.success);?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the data type 'json' you need to use 'html' instead. ([source](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype))

```
$.post("adduser", data, function(responseData){
    $('#content').html(responseData.success);
}, "html");
```

Comment: I changed it to html, but if do

    console.log(responseData.success)

I get undefined. Should I be sending back plain text/html? Or in JSON format? Neither seem to be working for me.

Comment: Actually, nevermind. I didn't take out the '.success' after responseData. Thanks!